# Give a file in the public folder the power to read env variables during build like index.html does

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, vue-cli

**EDIT:**

1. I already have environment variables configured in this vue-cli . project. But I can't use them in a file inside public.
2. Basically, what i want is give the same power that [the index file](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-index-file) already have to another file inside public folder. Access environment variables during build.

I have a .js file in my app that I want to be able to use an environment variable inside. but I didn't find a method of how to add static files to a public folder of the project and Vue still processes these files.

my file:

```js
var iframeOrigin = 'https://example.com';
var iframeProjectFolder = `${iframeOrigin}/chatbot-aliansce-web`;
var iframeEndPoint = `${iframeProjectFolder}/index.html`;

// var iframeOrigin = 'http://localhost:8080';
// var iframeProjectFolder = `${iframeOrigin}`;
// var iframeEndPoint = `${iframeProjectFolder}/index.html`;
```

I don't want to modify him every time I deploy in production.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't inject the script in a Vue file?

Comment: I can, but in this case i want to build an independent .js file, and make available to anyone add as as src for a script tag

Comment: How do you use this file in your code?

Comment: is a script that loads my app inside an iframe. Needs be at the same place every build. and i don't use him im my app.

Answer (score 2):

This is XY problem. Vue CLI makes `NODE_ENV`, `BASE_URL` and `VUE_APP_*` available at *compilation time* through `process.env`, while `process` is undefined at runtime. If a file needs to be processed, it should be located in `src` rather than `public`, then it can make use of environment variables.  Depending on how it's supposed to work with the rest of the application, the script could be separate entry point or a part of `main` appication.

A workaround is to expose compilation-time environment variables to global scope in the application, so they would be accessible outside:

```
window.appIframeOrigin = process.env.VUE_APP_IFRAME_ORIGIN;
```

Public script needs to be evaluated after the application in order for `appIframeOrigin` to become available.

Comment: it's a .js file that i want to be available to be added as a `src` in a `script` tag in any html page and loads my app inside a iframe, so need to be at the same name all the time.

Comment: how i configure vue to process this js file and make sure that he will be available at the build folder always with the same name?

Comment: You can disable hashes https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#filenamehashing for this and treat this script as just another app in the bundle by adding another entry point, https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages . This will disable hashes for other files but that's the price for the easiness of Vue CLI, otherwise you end up dealing with Webpack nuances to finetune the config.

Answer (score 0):

You can create environment variable using `.env` file.

> #### Environment Variables
>
> You can specify env variables by placing the following files in your project root:
>
> ```
> .env                # loaded in all cases
> .env.local          # loaded in all cases, ignored by git
> .env.[mode]         # only loaded in specified mode
> .env.[mode].local   # only loaded in specified mode, ignored by git
> ```
>
> An env file simply contains key=value pairs of environment variables:
>
> ```
> FOO=foo
> BAR=bar
>
> CONCAT=$FOO$BAR # CONCAT=foobar
> ```
>
> For more detailed env parsing rules, please refer to the documentation of dotenv.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i already using environment variables in my project, but this static js file can't use this variables because Vue just move the file to my dist folder when i create a build

Comment: I think you'll have to checkout docker to manage that. It might be easier ways, but this is the one I know you can manage this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

You can install [dotenv npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to create env variables and define iframeOrigin in the local env file.

```sh
iframeOrigin:'http://localhost:8080';
iframeProjectFolder:`${iframeOrigin}`;
iframeEndPoint:`${iframeProjectFolder}/index.html`;
```

Now use these values using
`process.env.iframeOrigin`,
`process.env.iframeProjectFolder`,
`process.env.iframeEndPoint`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i already using environment variables in my project, but this js file can't use this variables because Vue just move the file to my dist folder when i create a build.